# Cannot convert expression type 'void' to return type 'FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult'

Tags: c#, validation

This should not be a difficult question to answer, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this error is being thrown.

I have a validation result that I am trying to add a failure to if a condition is hit.

```
ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult();
//Do not call if nothing is in list.
if (List.Count == 0)
{
    ValidationFailure failure = new ValidationFailure("Nothing","Must pick something"){CustomState = ValidationLevel.Critical};
    return view.policyResult.Errors.Add(failure);
}
    return manager.Validate();
```

Please let me know if something sticks out!
I added the return statement if the list is greater than 0. It just goes off to a manager, validates, and returns a validation result.

Comment: it goes to a manager for validation. I just realized "return view.policyResult" was in here, but that is okay because it is a validationResult{get;set;}

Comment: I am new to this and didn't realize pressing enter actually submitted the comment. The manager is called and returns a validation result :)

Answer (score 1):

`Add` doesn't return anything, it's a `void` method.  You'll need to call add and then return...whatever it is you want to return (perhaps the `failure` object you created previously?).

i.e.

```
view.policyResult.Errors.Add(failure);
return failure;
```

Comment: Thank you guys! view.policyResult.Errors.Add(Failure); return failure worked. The only thing I changed was the return. I returned a validation result, so the final line is return view.policyResult. Thank you for prompt response

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 view.policyResult.Errors.Add(failure);
```

calls a method Add that has no return value (void) while the method in which this line is called requires to return an instance of an object of type `FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult`

If the class ValidationFailure derives from ValidationResult then you could try to return

```
  return failure ;
```

However there is  the possibility that your method doesn't enter the if condition (List.Count > 0) and we don't know what happen next.
Again, just a guess, but you want to return the `result` instance of `ValidationResult` declared before the if

Comment: Unfortunately, the method that I am in is "private ValidationResult" so the ValidationResult must be returned. I overlooked the fact that you cannot return view.policyResult.Errors.Add(failure), but instead have to place them on 2 lines; 1 to add the failure, and one to return the validation result that now has the failure attached. This makes much more sense to me now!!

Comment: So your method requires a ValidationResult, it is not clear how do you attach the ValidationFailure instance to the result variable and when you return this instace.

Comment: Yes, that is a bit confusing. The ValidationResult is being returned and validated. If upon return there are any errors then an error box is shown on the page. The check for the error is if(ValidationResult.IsValidBasedOnCustomState). The ValidationFailure has {CustomState = ValidationLevel.Critical} which makes the ValidationResult invalid. ValidationResult.Errors.Add(failure) adds the failure and the critical error. Hopefully I explained this well enough

Answer (score 0):

`Add` is a `void` method in C#. In order to return the custom failure message that you want, you need to call `return` and the failure object that you created.

As Steve pointed out, is it possible you haven't entered the if statement but try to add

```
return failure;
```